# Oracle11 global temp table lifespan

Tags: oracle11g

I created a global temp table using the following DDL:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TEMP_TABLE 
(
  column1  NUMBER,
  column2  NUMBER
)  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
```

Then I put some data into it and can read it fine.

I close my SQL client session and reopened it and the table is still there but has no data.

Am I correct in my observation that global temp tables persist between sessions just like regular permanent tables yet the data within them is lived only as long as the session in which it is populated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.

A global temporary table exists forever, just like any other database object.  It is created when you install your application (not at runtime) just like any other database object.

If you specify `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, the data persists for the lifetime of the session (and is only visible to the session that inserted it).  If you specify `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`, the data persists only for the lifetime of the transaction (and is only visible to the transaction that inserted it).

Comment: The part I don't understand is "It is created when you install your application (not at runtime)"

Comment: @foampile - Global temporary tables are created by the same installation scripts that create all the permanent tables in your application.  Unlike other databases where you create local temporary tables at runtime, you would not want to create a global temporary table at runtime (just like you would not create new tables at runtime).